# Scala - Pass in Seq to method that takes in _*

Tags: scala

If I have a method that looks like this:

```
def method(args: String*) = // something
```

And a sequence that looks like this:

`val s = Seq("a", "b", "c")`

How can I achieve the equivalent of this:

```
method(s)
```

Comment: You mean `method(s: _ *)` ? There is surely a duplicate question somewhere about this.

Comment: @m-z which you can [look up using symbolhound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=_*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @m-z mentioned, the answer is:

```
method(s:_*)
```